# GetProcAddress() returns Nil for a .NET DLL

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, com, delphi-6

I'm trying to call a .NET DLL from Delphi 6.

The dynamic loading of the DLL using `LoadLibrary()` is working fine, and a handle is returned.

```pascal
Handle := LoadLibrary(PChar(DLLName));
```

But, the `GetProcAddress()` function is returning `nil`, even though `Handle` is valid, and the function 'DLL_Version' exists.

```pascal
GetProcAddress(Handle, 'DLL_Version');
```

The DLL code is posted below

```cs
[Guid("14fd1190-df04-488c-ab0f-b120ea3e3f3a")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class UnManClass
{
  [DllExport]
  public static int DLL_Version()
  {
     return 251;
  }
}
```

I've used [UnmanagedExports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports) nuget package to support the **[DllExport]** in C#.

Here is the DumpBin output:

[image]

Is there any way to solve this issue, or any alternative methods which work?

Comment: How do you know that the DLL exports the `DLL_Version` function?

Comment: When `GetProcAddress()` fails, use `GetLastError()` to find out why. But the most common reason is because the requested function does not exist. Double-check that, such as with a tool like [TDUMP](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/TDUMP.EXE,_the_File_Dumping_Utility). Make sure the function is actually exported at all, and that it is exported using the *exact spelling* you are expecting. What does the .NET code look like that is implementing and exporting the function?

Comment: Did you follow *"You have to set your platform target to either x86, ia64 or x64. AnyCPU assemblies cannot export functions."*?

Comment: GetLastError() returns 127. The DLL is build for x86. Also tried with AnyCPU

Comment: 127 is "ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND: The specified procedure could not be found.".

Comment: Maybe you need to remove the `static` keyword from the C# routine.

Comment: @R.Hoek Nope, look at the [example](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports#TOC-Basic-sample).

Comment: Could not find the examples on nuget. But looking at those examples, I noticed the `ComVisible` attribute is not used for the class and in the mashall example the class is marked as `static`.

Comment: The function is exported. I've verified with DumpBin and screenshot is attatched above

Comment: @R.Hoek On the nuget page, there is a "Project Site" link.

Comment: @Berlin13 The function seems to be exported indeed. Are you sure you're loading the correct DLL from Delphi? Maybe you have several versions of the DLL in different directories?

Comment: @Berlin13 is the function actually being exported *by name*, or *by ordinal*? Your `GetProcAddress()` failure would suggest the latter, not the former. Does `GetProcAddress(Handle, MakeIntResource(0));` work?

Comment: Clearly the dll loaded doesn't export a function with that namr

Comment: In LoadLibrary, use a full path to your DLL to be sure the correct DLL is loaded. Make sure LoadLibrary doesn't return 0.

Comment: @fpiette `ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND` means that a DLL has been loaded

Comment: @Oliver The DLL is called by full path

Comment: @remy-lebeau GetProcAddress(Handle, MakeIntResource(0)) works. Can you please post it as answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Delphi to call a .NET DLL, you can trying like this:

```
var 
  OBJ: Variant;
begin 
   try 
      OBJ := CreateOleObject('DLLName.UnManClass');
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(OBJ.DLL_Version));
   finally
      OBJ := Unassigned;
   end;
end
```